# Sql query data validation in snowflake environment

Tags: sql, validation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two database say development and quality in snowflake. Currently I am running sql query on both database table separately. And storing the output separately.
And then doing manual data validation on both files using excel.
Is any way through any script or sql query automation kind of thing. For doing validation.

Thanks

Comment: We would certainly like to have more information on the validation part of the requirement here. Are we validating the data of the output for its integrity or are we trying to validation some connection/relation between the two output sets?

Comment: Validating the data of the output for its integrity.

Comment: Validating the data of the output for its integrity. We are matching, is dev database is as per QA or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to validate depending on your requirements. Suppose you want to validate columns data of table employee which exists is two different databases you can create an SQL script and run it to validate if there are any variances. Here is an example you can expand it further or build on it for your use case.

```
// Comparing data of tables in different databases
use role accountadmin;

create or replace database exampledb1;

use database exampledb1;
create or replace table employee

(   id int,
    FirstName  varchar(20),
    LastName   varchar(20),
    email      varchar(50) 
);

insert into employee values 
(1,'Sarah', 'Janes','sarah.janes@hotmail.com'),
(2,'Richard', 'Hays','richard.hays@gmail.com'),
(3,'Maria', 'Khan','maria.khan@wow.com');

create or replace database exampledb2;
use database exampledb2;
create or replace table employee

(   id  int,
    FirstName  varchar(20),
    LastName   varchar(20),
    email      varchar(50) 
);

insert into employee values 
(1,'Sarah', 'Janes','sarah.janes@hotmail.com'),
(2,'Richard1', 'Hays','richard.hays@gmail.com'),
(3,'Maria', 'Khan','maria.khan@wow.com');
 
 // Check the variance by comparing hash of each row
 // You should have correct access to both databases, scheam and underlying tables
 
 with qadata as
 (
 select id,hash(FirstName||LastName||email) as r1, FirstName, LastName,Email
 from exampledb2.public.employee as r1
 ),
 proddata as
 (
 select id,hash(t.FirstName||t.LastName||t.email) as r1, FirstName, LastName,Email
 from exampledb1.public.employee as t
  )
  select prod.id,
         case when prod.r1 = qa.r1 then 'Matched' else 'Variance' end as CheckStatus,
         prod.FirstName, 
         prod.LastName,
         prod.Email, 
         qa.FirstName, 
         qa.LastName,
         qa.Email
  from qadata qa 
  inner join proddata prod on qa.id=prod.id;
```

Here is the output column CheckStatus will identify whether row data matches or if there is a variance as shown for row 2.
[Comparison results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkV4l.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will Check out and let you know.

Comment: @AshishRaj have you been able to check? the solution shared was just an example how you can compare two tables in two. different databases as you requested. please share your findings